# Terraform choosing query parameters for API gateway

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the api gateway module at present supports only path parameter in the request_parameter section

```
request_parameters = {
        "method.request.path.url" = var.api_gw_request_method_path_url
      }
```

, but i want use the module to accept the query parameter string as well

```
request_parameters = {
        "method.request.queryStringParameters.url" = var.api_gw_request_method_queryStringParameters_url
      }
```

here is the sample code with existing usage

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "request_method" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.api_resource.id
  http_method   = var.api_gw_method
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.url" = var.api_gw_request_method_path_url
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Could you please try to reword your question, and maybe show some examples of what you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this third-party module, but based on the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method#request_parameters) try

```
request_parameters = {
    "method.request.querystring.url" = var.api_gw_request_method_queryStringParameters_url
}
```

This assumes `url` is a query string parameter.